# Is there a way to write jQuery code in Prototype js?

Tags: jquery, prototype

I have to do some stuff in prototype and it is really weird for me so i wondering if somehow i can write jquery code in prototype functions ? maybe it's a stupid question, but i have to ask:)

exemple. I have smth like this in prototype:

```
AfterFormValidate: function(result, form){      
        if(!result){
            $$('div.validation-advice,div.validation-advice-rtl').each(function(e){
                if(e.style.display != 'none'){
                    e.scrollTo();
                    throw $break;
                }
            });         
        }else{        
            $('submit-btn').addClassName('disabled').disabled = true;        
        }
        $$(".validation-advice-container").each( function (val,i) {
            alert(val.innerHTML);
        });
    },
```

and i want to write jquery code in that functions. is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, look at [jquery.noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Answer (score 3):

There is no "jQuery code". jQuery is a javascript library, and you use its functions [like `$( selector ).doSomething()` or `$.someGeneralPurposeFunction`.

You *could* use jQuery in a prototype context [like you would use jQuery selectors in Backbone for instance], but I strongly advise against it: pick one single DOM manipulation library, it would not be that hard to write some prototype.js code.

Comment: ok, im not familiar with backbone, so i don;t really understand what you mean. can you explain me otherwise? thx for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery noConfict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) method... not sure if is suitable for your needs